# UITableview Inside UICollectionview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have design prototype where designer design like there is a `UITableView`'s cell.When user tap on the `UITableViewCell`,the `UITableViewCell` expands, and one row add into the `UITableView`. Expanded cell having `UICollectionView`, and collection view data fetched from the API.

I am having issue like when i tap on the cell, the height of that cell getting increase,But when i suddenly tap again on that cell, the cell height should decrease automatically. But that revised height does not reflect on `UITableView` it keeps the expanded cell height.

I want like according to `UITableViewCell` height, the `UITableView` height adjust automatically.

Can any one share the link of source code of `UITableView` inside `UICollectionView`, That will really helpful?